# How to represent "event" in a UML Class Diagram?

Tags: events, uml, class-diagram

This is my code snippet

```cs
public class Notation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Notes _note;
}
```

**How to write** `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;` **in UML Class diagram properly?**

First, I think it's:

> +PropertyChanged: PropertyChangedEventHandler

But then, I realized that it doesn't represent the `event` part of the code.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can the c# .net event construct best be represented in a UML class diagram?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299442/how-can-the-c-sharp-net-event-construct-best-be-represented-in-a-uml-class-diag)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the UML stereotype in the game. Just stereotype this property:

[image]

Note that `_note` is a plain, private property.

Comment: Is it standard UML? Can't find that here: https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/Superstructure/PDF

Comment: What can't you find? All the elements are standard UML, it's up to you how to apply them.

Comment: I meant the «event» stereotype for the attribute.

Comment: You are free to use whatever stereotype you wish. You give it a meaning. UML has some standard stereotypes, but you can add your own ones.

Answer (score 6):

You can define receptions in class definition. Reception is type of behavioral feature. If you define it, instance of class can accept signal events from environment.

Other way to define events in UML is using behavioral diagrams.

- Activity diagram has event element to accept events of specific types during execution.
- State Machine diagram has transitions with trigger definition, which represents event acceptance as well.
- Interaction diagram represents events as receiving or sending messages.

Behavior definitions (represented by behavioral diagrams) can be assigned to class definition as classifier behavior or owned behaviors. Owned behavior definition defines ability of owning class to react on event occurrences.

Your example just defines attribute of class, but not ability to accept event by class instance.

Comment: a useful explanation. But I still prefer the simpler one as my accepted answer. Thanks!